# Running Llama 2 on Mac using HuggingFace

Tags: huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, llama

I am trying to run Llama 2 model from HuggingFace. Strangely these lines work fine on Colab, but give an error on Mac.

Code:

```
    from transformers import AutoTokenizer
    import transformers
    import torch

    model = "meta-llama/Llama-2-13b-hf"
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)
```

Error on Mac:
Exception: data did not match any variant of untagged enum PyNormalizerTypeWrapper at line 49 column 3

Any suggestions for how to resolve this? Google search not helpful.

Thanks,
Kushal.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue with the 7b model on M2 MBP

from transformers import pipeline
pipe = pipeline("text-generation", model="meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf")

runs into data did not match any variant of untagged enum PyNormalizerTypeWrapper at line 49 column 3